# How to use @LocalPort together with @DynamicPropertySource in a SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-test

we have the following configuration

application-local.yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/jwks
```

application-production.yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://auth.foo.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

When running on localhost, we have a Controller in place which mocks the OAuth2 Endpoints and returning self-signed Tokens.

Everything is working as expected when using a static port.

We struggled to override the property `jwt-set-uri` with a dynamic port in a SpringBootTest while using `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`

According to the Docs `@DynmicPropertSource` should be a perfect fit
but is required to be static (meaning part of the companion object in Kotlin)

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class Test {

@LocalServerPort
private var port = 0

 companion object {
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun registerUrl(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri", "???")
        }
    }
}
```

My question:
I"m probably missing something here but how is it possible to access the non static port in the static context of @DynamicPropertySource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@LocalServerPort` is a property you can annotate it with `@JvmStatic`. You would then be able to use it in your `@DynamicPropertySource`

Comment: Adding the annotation leads to the following error:

Only members in named objects and companion objects can be annotated with '@JvmStatic'

Comment: so place the localServerPort in the companion object :)

Comment: Thanks, this seems indeed to work. 
Didn"t knew it was possible